# Many to Many relation with join table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 models with a many-to-many relationship, `event` and `category`. I am trying to put together a query which let's me get the events by the category name.

I have the following tables:

category

```
id | name
```

event

```
id | name
```

event_categories_join

```
category_id | event_id
```

I've successfully gotten the events from the category id by inner joining the pivot table.

```
SELECT * FROM event
INNER JOIN event_categories_join
ON event.id = event_categories_join.event_id
WHERE event_categories_join.category_id = 5
```

How do I do this by the name instead of the id?

---

*edit*:

I three categories, Concert, Easter and Talks. I also an event, London Grammar which belongs to the categories Concert and Easter. Now I want to write a query where I provide the *name* of the category, and get the belonging events - in this case Concert.

Comment: Add some sample data and expected output, and it will be easier to understand what you are asking for. (Category name or event name...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need another join. Try something like

```
SELECT * FROM event
INNER JOIN event_categories_join ON event.id = event_categories_join.event_id
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = event_categories_join.category_id
WHERE category.name = 'my_category';
```

As a side note: You should reconsider renaming event_categories_join to just `event_categories`. Or maybe `event_categories_mapping`. This is most probably more true to the domain in question, while the join naming is to tightly coupled with the fact we're dealing with a relational database.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT temp.* FROM (
  SELECT event.id as eventid,event.name as eventName ,event_categories_join.* FROM event AS event 
INNER JOIN event_categories_join
ON event.eventid= event_categories_join.event_id 
) AS temp 
INNER JOIN category AS category ON 
category.id =temp.category_id
WHERE category.name = 'Maeh'
```